# Woocommerce currency switcher and widget placement

Tags: currency, woocommerce

How do I place widgets anywhere I want?

I have a widget that changes the currency in my store. 
But I only know how to add it to the side bar. (drag and drop)

Is there a way I can code it in so that it appears in a more normal place during check out?

I am using [woocommerce and a dev.p2e.net plugin](http://dev.pathtoenlightenment.net/shop/currency-switcher-woocommerce/) currency switcher.

Here's my [site](http://www.bodesi.com)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it's a matter of adding a widget area to the theme and drop the widget there. One of my customers reported that he was able to add a widget on the page using the [Widget Anywhere plugin](http://wpeden.com/product/widget-anywhere/), but I haven't tried it myself.

### Update 26/06/2014

The currency selector widget now can also be displayed using a shortcode, as follows:

```
[aelia_currency_selector_widget title="Widget title (optional)" widget_type="dropdown|buttons"]
```

If you would like to call the shortcode from your template's code, you can use WordPress' `do_shortcode()` function. Please refer to the WordPress Codex for the instructions on how to do it: [WordPress Function Reference/do shortcode/](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode)

Further reading

- [Plugin's knowledge base](https://aelia.freshdesk.com/solution/categories/120257/folders/197723/articles/121618-i-would-like-to-add-the-currency-selector-widget-somewhere-in-my-theme-how-can-i-do)